# Xorg randomly crashes

Tags: 12.04, xorg, 64-bit

I keep getting a crash report saying Xorg has crashed. It usually happens when I log in, but sometimes occurs afterwards. When I get the crash, nothing appears to be having trouble, so the first couple times I ignored it. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 with xorg package "xserver-xorg-core 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.1"

Comment: Have you [submitted the crash report and reported the bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)?

Comment: Yeah, still no info back. when I went to submit the crash report it recommended asking on here.

Comment: Can you put a link to the crash report in your question? If it's private, and you don't want to change its visibility to public, then having the link in your question will still help once CoreDump.gz is removed and other files inspected for potentially sensitive information disclosure (as at that point a triager will make your bug public).

Comment: I have rep points... just not ubuntu yet, so this is a comment for @michael If I remove the NVidia driver, can I adjust my prime profiles?? I'm having this crash on Ubuntu 14.04 running gnome3 desktop enviro. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the bug report 973096](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/973096), someone suggests to "just remove the Nvidia driver and use the standard nouveau driver until this bug is fixed".